# Calling conversation cleanup from outlook add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to call outlook's conversation cleanup from my outlook addin (c# + vsto).
I have my button on the office ribbon bar and on clicking it it needs to invoke outlook's conversation cleanup on the currently selected mail item.
Is this possible and how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook items provide the [GetConversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869870(v=office.15).aspx) method which obtains a `Conversation` object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs.

`GetConversation` returns `Null` (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no conversation exists for the item. No conversation exists for an item in the following scenarios:

•The item has not been saved. An item can be saved programmatically, by user action, or by auto-save.

•For an item that can be sent (for example, a mail item, appointment item, or contact item), the item has not been sent.

•Conversations have been disabled through the Windows registry.

•The store does not support Conversation view (for example, Outlook is running in classic online mode against a version of Microsoft Exchange earlier than Microsoft Exchange Server 2010). Use the IsConversationEnabled property of the Store object to determine whether the store supports Conversation view.

The following code example assumes that the selected item in the explorer window is a mail item. The code example gets the conversation that the selected mail item is associated with, and enumerates each item in that conversation, displaying the subject of the item. The `DemoConversation` method calls the `GetConversation` method of the selected mail item to get the associated Conversation object. `DemoConversation` then calls the `GetTable` and `GetRootItems` methods of the Conversation object to get a Table object and SimpleItems collection, respectively.

```
void DemoConversation() 
{ 
   object selectedItem = 
    Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]; 
   // This example uses only 
   // MailItem. Other item types such as 
   // MeetingItem and PostItem can participate 
   // in the conversation. 
   if (selectedItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
   { 
      // Cast selectedItem to MailItem. 
      Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
          selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
      // Determine the store of the mail item. 
      Outlook.Folder folder = mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
      Outlook.Store store = folder.Store; 
      if (store.IsConversationEnabled == true) 
      { 
         // Obtain a Conversation object. 
         Outlook.Conversation conv = mailItem.GetConversation(); 
         // Check for null Conversation. 
         if (conv != null) 
         { 
             // Obtain Table that contains rows 
             // for each item in the conversation. 
             Outlook.Table table = conv.GetTable(); 
             Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items Count: " + 
             table.GetRowCount().ToString()); 
             Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Table:"); 
             while (!table.EndOfTable) 
             { 
                 Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow(); 
                 Debug.WriteLine(nextRow["Subject"] 
                 + " Modified: " 
                 + nextRow["LastModificationTime"]); 
             } 
             Debug.WriteLine("Conversation Items from Root:"); 
             // Obtain root items and enumerate the conversation. 
             Outlook.SimpleItems simpleItems 
              = conv.GetRootItems(); 
             foreach (object item in simpleItems) 
             { 
                 // In this example, only enumerate MailItem type. 
                 // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
                 // can appear in the conversation. 
                 if (item is Outlook.MailItem) 
                 { 
                     Outlook.MailItem mail = item 
                      as Outlook.MailItem; 
                     Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
                      mail.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
                     string msg = mail.Subject 
                     + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
                     Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
                 } 
                 // Call EnumerateConversation 
                 // to access child nodes of root items. 
                 EnumerateConversation(item, conv); 
              } 
           } 
        } 
     } 
  } 


  void EnumerateConversation(object item, 
        Outlook.Conversation conversation) 
  { 
       Outlook.SimpleItems items = 
            conversation.GetChildren(item); 
       if (items.Count > 0) 
       { 
          foreach (object myItem in items) 
          { 
              // In this example, only enumerate MailItem type. 
              // Other types such as PostItem or MeetingItem 
              // can appear in the conversation. 
              if (myItem is Outlook.MailItem) 
              { 
                  Outlook.MailItem mailItem = 
                    myItem as Outlook.MailItem; 
                  Outlook.Folder inFolder = 
                    mailItem.Parent as Outlook.Folder; 
                  string msg = mailItem.Subject 
                  + " in folder " + inFolder.Name; 
                  Debug.WriteLine(msg); 
               } 
               // Continue recursion. 
               EnumerateConversation(myItem, conversation); 
            } 
         } 
      }
```

Comment: Eugene, Thanks for replying to my queries. In order to use above approach we will have to compare each message body with the body of every other message present in the table. Other than that I found Outlook has body text for different cases (In some message body there is 'mailto:' and email address is surrounded by '[' brackets while it uses '<' brackets elsewhere, in some places seconds are present in the time field). Therefore it might be better to just invoke outlook's built-in conversation cleanup feature instead of reinventing the wheel.